# display a herocard using luis action binding

Tags: node.js, azure-language-understanding

How to create and display a "HeroCard" within the fulfill() function of LUIS action binding using node.js ? I am following the samples provided by the microsoft(https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/blog-LUISActionBinding)

Here is that how I tried to do this...

```
fulfill: function (parameters, callback) {
    utilities.FilterFunction(parameters.x, parameters.y).then(function (matches){

       utilities.CreateCard(session, matches).then(function(cards){

            var reply = new builder.Message(session)
                .attachmentLayout(builder.AttachmentLayout.carousel)
                .attachments(cards);

            callback(util.format(reply));
        });

    });
}
```

How can I use session value in the fulfill method?...without session "utilities.CreateCard" won't work...

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `session` is not available in the action's fulfill method, we can make call to only to the `utilities.FilterFunction` and return the result via the `callback`. Now in our main js file, in the `fulfillReplyHandler` we get the `actionModel` which contains the result from `utilities.FilterFunction`.

Now we can create the "HeroCard" using the "session" that is accessible in the `fulfillReplyHandler`.